# matplotlib PdfPages - storing a lossy copy of a plot with lots of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdfpages

I'm creating plots with matplotlib.pyplot and writing them to pdf.  Some of these plots have largeish (up to 100,000) points and obviously have a lot of overlapping points, i.e. certain parts of the chart are just a solid mass.  (That's okay - I'm interested in what the sparser parts of the graph look like.)

When I save these plots to pdf, it takes a long time to write, and reading the pdf is even worse.  Is there a way to store a "lossy" copy of the plot in the pdf?  For example, if I took a screenshot of the plot and embedded it in the pdf, it would load a lot faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend trying to plot with the option `rasterized`:

```
pts = np.random.rand(2, 100000)
plt.scatter(*pts, rasterized=True)
plt.savefig('rast.pdf')
```

For comparison:

```
plt.scatter(*pts)
plt.savefig('reg.pdf')
```

And

```
$ ls -lh tmp*.pdf
177K Dec  9 22:03 tmp_rast.pdf
1.5M Dec  9 22:02 tmp_reg.pdf
```